# JSON formatting of image

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm having difficulties getting my list to display as intended. Can anyone help please?

I have a list, and one column is a calculated field which points to a JPG file. These are A4, scanned at 300dpi. The JSON formatting is *intended* to display a very small sub-section of the image -- but I do not appear to get things to work as intended.

My approach so far has been to (1) select the portion of the image I want, then (2) scale it to size. I do **not** want to use an image editor to cut out the relevant section. This has to be done using CSS.

If I mock up a normal HTML page, this gives an idea of what I expect:

```
img {
border: 1px solid red;
border-radius: 8px;
width: 1000px;
height: 320px;
object-position: 60% 73%;
object-fit: none;
transform: scale(.2, .2);
}
</style>
```

So, my JSON string is:

```
{
"elmType": "a",
"attributes": {
"href": "@currentField",
"target": "_blank"
},
"children": [
{
"elmType": "img",
"style": {
  "border": "1px solid red",
  "border-radius": "8px",
  "width": "1000px",
  "height": "320px",
  "object-position": "60% 73%",
  "object-fit": "none",
  "transform": "scale(.2, .2)"
},
"attributes": {
"src": "@currentField"
}
}
]
}
```

However, this gives no image whatsoever. If I remove the transform, I do get an image, but (a) it's not the correct portion of the image, and (b) it is, of course, far too large.

Is there a way I can solve this? Rather than use transform, could I potentially crop the correct portion of the image into a DIV, and then auto-scale that to a final size of 100x32px? Or is there another potential approach?

Many thanks.

Comment: Alas, no. It appears that my initial approach is not possible with the current SharePoint implementation. What is not yet clear is whether this is absolutely not possible, or whether it could be achieved but using a totally different approach. I'm still testing...

Comment: It is not possible using SharePoint JSON for sure. You might need to build custom solution (maybe SPFx field customizer) for your requirements. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi @Phil, does my below answer help you in any way? Let me know if you need any further help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using SharePoint Online JSON formatting capabilities.

SharePoint JSON formatting does not support `object-position` and transform `scale` style.

SharePoint JSON only supports `translate(arg)` and `translate(arg, arg)` for `transform` style.

You can check list of supported styling properties at: [SharePoint JSON formatting - style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#style)

---

**Update**:

You will have to use the SPFx Field Customizer extension for your requirements to customize the display of SharePoint list column.

Check this Microsoft official documentation: [Build your first Field Customizer extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer)

You can find some SPFx samples which might help you to get started with at: [SPFx extension samples](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/main/samples/) - check folders with name contains `-field-`.